# CSS show element attribute value, not element content

Tags: css, xml

I have elements with this pattern (XML, not HTML, but CSS should still work):

```
<expan abbr="XX">YY</expan>
```

Sometimes I want to see "YY" in the output, sometimes I want to see "XX".  No problem when I want to see "YY" and not the attribute value: just leave it as is.  No problem if I want to see BOTH the element content and the attribute value: this bit of CSS does that:

```
      expan:after {content:attr(abbr);}
```

will display <expan abbr="XX">YY</expan> as "YYXX".

But: problem if I want to see the attribute value and NOT the element content -- that is, if I want to see just "XX".  I can use either CSS display or visibility to hide the element <expan>.  But it hides EVERYTHING, including the :after pseudo-element.  So, this code:

```
      expan:after {content:attr(abbr);}

      expan {display:none;}
```

Shows nothing at all.

So, good folk... help.  This seems a very obvious thing to want to do.  Of course, I could do it pretty easily manipulating the DOM with Javascript.  But for various reasons, I don't have that option.  I'd like to do it with simple CSS.  Can I??

Comment: Seems to work with [visibility](http://jsfiddle.net/tfmVL/), but not in IE. Why do you need this anyway? Sounds like you need two separate elements, not abbr+after

Comment: Have you tried any hackery like using a before: pseudo-element as a mask to cover the main element or to contain what would normally be in the main element(YY)?

Comment: Course, I could use two elements (or more).  I just very much prefer not to, on the Ockam's razor principle.  Visibility was not working for me in Chrome -- what value were you using?

Comment: @Niall that's what my answer does: it hides and covers the main element. Not totally accessible, but it works OK.

Comment: Ian: no, same problem as I note below. Try this with onelong<expan abbr="YY">XXXX</expan>word: you end up with a gap in the middle of the word, either before or after the YY:ugly, as I said.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll have to use some kind of hack where the element is still there but only the pseudo element (`:after`) is visible to the user. An example of this would be `color`. If you know it's only text, then you can set the `color` to `transparent` on the main element, and set it to a real color on the pseudo. You'll still have a blank space to deal with, but you can fix that with `position: relative` on the parent and `position: absolute` on the pseudo element, because the pseudo element is a child of the main element. note that the text is still there, but you only see it if you highlight it with the mouse. That's fixable too, with `::selection`, but it would still be copyable by accident, and `::select` is only available in modern browsers.

Here is a demo showing what I mean: [DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/5580835)

EDIT: This one should work with text around it, but you'll have to increase the `width` in order to add more text: [DEMO](http://dabblet.com/gist/5582867)

Works for me in Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Well, this *almost* works perfectly.  Yes, the content of the expan element can't be seen.  And, you can see the attribute in expan:before or expan:after.  BUT -- and a big but -- the unseen content takes up space in the browser window.  So if the expan element appears in the middle of a word (and it often does) you end up with extra space in the middle of the word. Ugly.

Comment: Just tried your site with onelong<expan abbr="XX">YYYY</expan>word -- and ended up with nasty space.  Unless the abbr text is EXACTLY the same length as the expan text, you get nasty space in the middle of the word

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: Ian: playing around with the values of width and left position does indeed eliminate the spacing -- so this is probably good enough for what I am trying to do (which is a 'preview' view, as part of an editing system -- so not the final production view, for which I will have many more and better technologies).  So I vote this the best solution.  It works in Chrome and Firefox fine.

Comment: It looks like the website I was using to host the images deleted them.

Comment: @Ian I'm sorry, I don't remember, maybe only the images were missing but the links worked. Anyway thanks for editing your answer, I'll remove my comments soon.

Answer (score 2):

One partial solution is to set the expan `font-size` to 0 and the `:before` content `font-size` to the desired size:

```
expan:before {
    content: attr(name);
    font-size: 15px;
}
expan {
    font-size: 0;
}
```

Trying to set the `:before` `font-size` to 100% did not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can only set the 'content:' attribute on ::before and ::after psuedo-elements.
But what you can do is just provide *both* your texts in two separate attributes, like this:

```
<div long-text="This is very long text" short-text="Short text">
   <!-- this part is empty -->
</div>
```

Then your CSS can switch between them like this:

```
.AltText::before { content:attr(long-text); }

@media screen and (max-width:1200px) {
  #HeaderTabContainer .AltText::before { content:attr(short-text); }
}
```

Or you could use a third attribute to toggle between them.